# How can I highlight selected text in a Text view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I display a text in different colors and the user needs to be able to copy a portion of said text. I want them to be able to highlight the text they want to copy (like in a pdf or in a messenger/email).

Since I need different colors I used multiple Text views in a VStack:

```
    var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
        Spacer()
        ForEach(logMessages, id: \.id) { message in
            messageText(message)
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .padding()
}

    private func messageText(_ message: LogMessage) -> some View {
    return
        Text("\(message.levelString): \(message.message)")
            .font(.system(size: fontSize))
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .foregroundColor(logColor(message.level.rawValue))
            .textSelection(.enabled)
    //                .background( // meant to be for highlighting selected text
    //                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
    //                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
    //                        .opacity(0.3)
    //                )
        }
```

I want the .background part to be my highlighting for the selected text.

I couldn't find any information on how to tackle this specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `Text` view in SwiftUI does not natively support text selection. However, you can create a custom TextSelectable view to enable text selection functionality by the help of uikit code that you can merge in swiftui using UIViewRepresentable. I have attached the whole where I tested the selection functionality.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TextSelectionView: View {
    let logMessages: [LogMessage] = [
        LogMessage(levelString: "Info", message: "This is an information message.", level: 1),
        LogMessage(levelString: "Warning", message: "This is a warning message.", level: 2),
        LogMessage(levelString: "Error", message: "This is an error message.", level: 3)
    ]
    
    @State private var selectedRange: NSRange?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Spacer()
            ForEach(logMessages, id: \.id) { message in
                messageText(message, selectedRange: $selectedRange)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .padding()
    }
    
    private func messageText(_ message: LogMessage, selectedRange: Binding<NSRange?>) -> some View {
        var selectedRange: NSRange?
        
        let text = TextSelectable(text: "\(message.levelString): \(message.message)", selectedRange: selectedRange) { range in
            selectedRange = range
        }
            .font(.system(size: 14))
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                    .foregroundColor(selectedRange != nil ? .blue.opacity(0.3) : .clear)
            )
        return text
    }
    
}

struct TextSelectionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TextSelectionView()
    }
}

struct TextSelectable: UIViewRepresentable {
    let text: String
    var selectedRange: NSRange?
    var onSelectedRangeChanged: ((NSRange?) -> Void)?
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.isSelectable = true
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        
        if uiView.selectedRange != selectedRange {
            uiView.selectedRange = selectedRange ?? NSRange(location: 0, length: 0)
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        let parent: TextSelectable
        
        init(_ parent: TextSelectable) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
            parent.onSelectedRangeChanged?(textView.selectedRange)
        }
    }
}

struct LogMessage: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let levelString: String
    let message: String
    let level: Int
}
```

Here we passing NSRange state variable to TextSelectable binding which handle the selection of text. Feel free to ask question if you have.

Comment: I like the approach! Thanks!
I dropped some of the selectedRange uses, since it's a struct wide variable.
I don't really understand what a class inside a struct is supposed to mean / how that works. Could use some clarification here :)

I also have two issues with the solution:
1.) I can't wrap the VStack in a vertical scroll view -> then the Text vanishes.
2.) Xcode complains: "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior."

Comment: The use of class inside struct is the way to interact with uikit code in swiftui. A SwiftUI view that represents a UIKit view controller can define a Coordinator type that SwiftUI manages and provides as part of the representable view’s context. Please visit this link for more info https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit.